# Background photo doesnt cover whole page on client's machine

Tags: css, wordpress, background

really strange thing is happening to me right now. I am developing site for my client and this site has background photo. Background photo is displaying just fine on my PC in all browsers. But on client's pc in IE version 10.0.9200 and in Firefox 23.0.1. I tested it in the same version of browsers on my PC and it is displaying properly for me.

CSS is

```
body {
    background: url('img/pozadi-ukazkove.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

screen resolution is 1280x1024, it is the same for me and client
image is 1920x1080 and it is adapting to visitors resolution

web url is http://rosta.sperkobchod.cz/travel/wordpress/

how my client sees website - http://postimg.org/image/ewxx5e1z9/

any help pls?

Answer (score 1):

Using `width: 100%; height: 100%;` and `z-index: -1;` may help you. I may be wrong. Please correct me if I am.

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-size: cover` instead of `background-size: 100%` should resolve this issue : )